# Initialize and clean up per-test data for parallel tests in TestNG

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, testng

While migrating some tests from JUnit to TestNG, I'm facing an issue because of the difference in how these test frameworks treat their Test class instances.

JUnit creates a new instance of the Test class for each test method. So a common pattern I see is:

```
public class MyTest {

    private Stream inputData;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // Set up some data in (non-static) instance fields
        // This data is isolated per test
        inputData = createInputDataStream();
    }

    @Test
    public void testStuff() {
        // Use the data from the instance fields
        doStuff(inputData);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        // Clean up the data from the instance fields
        closeInputDataStream(inputData);
    }
}
```

In contrast, TestNG uses a single instance of the Test class for all test methods. So the pattern above does not work! Because data is stored in instance fields, the values are no longer isolated. This can cause overwritten data mid-test if parallel execution is enabled.

So how would I do this with TestNG? Is there a way to store data which is isolated to each `@BeforeMethod`-`@Test`-`@AfterMethod` tuple?

I can do all 3 steps inside the `@Test` itself, but that would require adding ungainly `try...finally` blocks to every test. I also tried using `ITestContext`, but it also seems to be shared for the entire test run.

Comment: `@BeforeMethod` and `@AfterMethod` do get called around each `@Test` invocation; so this is supposed to work exactly as you described. The only difference is that you get to override the class state every time -- rather than creating a new instance. Did you notice any unexpected behavior with that approach ? Or are you trying to run all the tests in the class in parallel (I'm afraid that's not possible) ?

Comment: @CostiCiudatu Mainly during parallel execution - the values sometimes get overwritten mid-test.

Comment: If you want to run the test methods within the class in parallel (`<suite parallel="methods" ...>`), there's no way to defend against race conditions, since you're altering mutable state.

Comment: @CostiCiudatu hence the question :) . JUnit provides me one solution. A DIY solution could maybe use `ThreadLocal`s. I want to find out if there's anything available out of the box in TestNG.

Comment: My feeling is that the solution in JUnit is broken (from a design perspective). You would never design a class to alter mutable state and provide "pseudo-synchronization" by having one instance per desired method invocation. Why are those methods in the same class in the first place ? To achieve the same result, you should perhaps define an abstract class containing the mutable state (together with the before and after methods) and then extend that class for every method you want to run in isolation (and this would be a lot more reasonable from an OOP perspective).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with TestNG you have way more power over those local variables that you did with JUnit AND the DataProvider handles your threading, per test-class-instance:

```
public class MyTest {

private Stream inputData;

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp(Object[] args) {
    inputData = (Data)args[0]; 
    inputData = normalizeDataBeforeTest(inputData);
}

@Test(dataProvider="testArgs")
public void testStuff(Data inputDatax, Object a, Object b) {
    doSomethingWith(a);
    doSomethingWith(b);
    doStuff(this.inputData);
}

@AfterMethod
public void tearDown() {
    // Clean up the data from the instance fields
    closeInputDataStream(inputData);
}

....
@DataProvider
public static Object[][] testArgs() {
    // generate data here, 1 row per test thread
  Object[][] testData;
  for loop {
      // add row of data to testData
      // {{dataItem, obja, objb}, {dataItem, obja, objb}} etc.
  }
  return testData;
}
}
```