# TestNG.java.lang.NullPointerException when running second @Test

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

It runs the first test OK, but then I'm getting a null pointer exception when running the "Edit Profile" test, and I'm not sure why.  I globally declared public driver.

```
public class TestLogin
{

    public WebDriver driver;// = new FirefoxDriver();

    public String baseURL = "mytestsite.com";

    @BeforeTest
    public void setBaseURL()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( 20L, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
        driver.get( baseURL );
    }

    // Login test
    @Test
      public void testLogin() throws InterruptedException{

      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

      analyticsLoginPage mylogin = PageFactory.initElements(driver,     `     `       analyticsLoginPage.class);
    analyticsLandingPage landingpage = mylogin.login("username", "password");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
   }

    // Edit Profile test

    @Test // (dependsOnMethods = { "testLogin" })
    public void verifyProfile()
        throws InterruptedException
    {
        // driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        Thread.sleep( 3000 );
        analyticsLandingPage landingpage = new analyticsLandingPage( driver );
        Thread.sleep( 3000 );
        landingpage.gotoProfile();

        // Thread.sleep(5000);
        analyticsEditProfilePage editprofile = PageFactory.initElements( driver, analyticsEditProfilePage.class );
        editprofile.verifyEditFirstName();
        editprofile.verifyEditLastName();
        editprofile.verifyCompanyName();
        editprofile.verifyReportingProfile();
        editprofile.verifyUsageStatistics();

}
```

Landing page class

```
package com.tapanalytics.pom.domain;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.security.auth.login.Configuration;

import org.junit.Test;

public class analyticsLandingPage
{

    WebDriver driver;

    public analyticsLandingPage( WebDriver driver )
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    @FindBy( xpath = Configuration.manage_dashboard )
    public WebElement manage_dashboard;

    @FindBy( xpath = Configuration.manage_services )
    public WebElement manage_services;

    @FindBy( xpath = Configuration.profile )
    public WebElement profile;

    @FindBy( xpath = Configuration.support )
    public WebElement support;

    @FindBy( xpath = Configuration.logout )
    public WebElement logout;

    public void gotoMangeDashboards()
    {
        manage_dashboard.click();
    }

    public void gotoServices()
    {
        manage_services.click();
    }

    public void gotoProfile()
    {
        profile.click();
    }

    public void gotoSupport()
    {
        support.click();
    }

    public void Logout()
    {
        logout.click();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the npe located ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you could fix this.  I think you could use a `@BeforeMethod` method that initializes the driver before each test method and then a `@AfterMethod` that calls **driver.quit()** and sets the driver to **null** after each test method.   The  non-static driver can remain the same as a class member.

Personally, with Selenium tests I never re-use the same driver for multiple test methods.  Your asking for trouble when you do that and you usually need to enforce test method order.

**More advanced:**  create your WebDriver instance in a data provider and then pass it into each test method.  Then, have a @AfterMethod that closes the driver after each test.  Then, your test class doesn't need to contain its own shared driver instance and TestNG handles your test multi-threading.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm currently using:@BeforeTest and after test to close browser.  @AfterTest
    public static void quitDriver(){
        driver.quit();
 }

Comment: Is that what you meant by passing from provider to each test:     analyticsLandingPage landingpage = new analyticsLandingPage( driver );

Comment: No, what I mean is that if you look at my example in this question and then replace WebDriverHelper object with "Object a", given that the helper has a createWebDriver method:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536537/initialize-and-clean-up-per-test-data-for-parallel-tests-in-testng/35066015#35066015    That is why i called it a advanced example, because it would take further explanation, not appropriate here.

Answer (score -1):

Try with

```
public static WebDriver driver;
```

in two classes.

Thank You,
Murali